# Convert Tensor of Integers to Tensor of Floats (Java)

Tags: java, tensorflow, detection

I have loaded an image into a tensor of Uint8s. I'm now trying to convert this to a tensor of floats so I can load it into my trained model.

For reference, here is how I got the Tensor of Uint8s:

ReadFile readFile = tf.io.readFile(fileName);

```
DecodeJpeg.Options options = DecodeJpeg.channels(3L);
DecodeJpeg decodeImage = tf.image.decodeJpeg(readFile.contents(), options);
Tensor image = runner.fetch(decodeImage).run().get(0);

Shape imageShape = runner.fetch(decodeImage).run().get(0).shape();
//reshape the tensor to 4D for input to model
Reshape<TUint8> reshape = tf.reshape(decodeImage,
   tf.array(1,
      imageShape.asArray()[0],
      imageShape.asArray()[1],
      imageShape.asArray()[2]
   )
);
```

But when I try to load this into my model via:

```
        Tensor reshapeTensor = s.runner().fetch(reshape).run().get(0);
```

I get the following error:
`org.tensorflow.exceptions.TFInvalidArgumentException: Expects arg[0] to be float but uint8 is provided`